# RichFaces on Secure Site

Tags: tomcat, https, richfaces

Has anyone used RichFaces on a secure site? I'm using the following:

Tomcat 6 RichFaces 3.3.1 (also tried 3.1.4.GA) intermediate certificate

My application is using the Rich panel bar. When using HTTPS, only the panel labels are rendered and I get the following JavaScript error:

'RichFaces' is undefined

This is the JavaScript creating the error: new Richfaces.PanelBar

When using HTTP, the panel bar renders as expected without any JavaScript errors.

So it appears the application is unable to find the necessary RichFaces Library when using HTTPS. I've been unable to locate any documentation regarding additional configuration for HTTPS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've looked into this further.

When using HTTPS resources located in the 
/context path/a4j/*/*.jsf is unavailable. 

If I try to reach the URL directly, for example:

/a4j/s/3_3_1.GAorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css
/basic_classes.xcss/DATB/eAFrvajdHLp8hjQAEgwDtA__.jsf

I get a 404.

When using standard HTTP, the resources under context path/a4j/* are available. The URL above is found and the source is opened.

Any ideas as to why these resources are unavailable when using HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

We are successfully using Richfaces over HTTPS (Apache->mod-jk->JBoss 5.1.0).  We haven't seen the exact but problem you're running into, but we did hit this issue https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBIDE-4500 https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/RF-7399][2](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/RF-7399). May or may not be helpful, be I at least wanted to confirm that you can run Richfaces over HTTPS just fine.

Answer (score 0):

When your application does not send files with a specific MIME TYPE information to the browser the browser tries to [guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing) the correct MIME TYPE.

This is more restrict under https than under http. In consequence this could lead to the 404 response you have observed.

Try defining all relevant file/MIME TYPE mappings in your web.xml.

eg.

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xcss</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```